# no xticks visible in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
def time_processes(proc_data):
  ax = sns.barplot()
  upper_x_bound = TIME_BOUND + 1
  lower_x_bound = 0
  tick_step_size = float(TIME_BOUND + 1 - lower_x_bound) / 40
  ax.set_xlim(lower_x_bound, upper_x_bound)
  xticks = np.arange(lower_x_bound, upper_x_bound, step=tick_step_size)

  for idx, (p_name, p_data) in enumerate(proc_data.items()):
      widths = p_data[:, 1] - p_data[:, 0]
      starts = p_data[:, 0]
      ax.barh(y=p_name, left=starts, width=widths)

  ax.grid()
  ax.set_xticks(xticks)
  return ax

time_processes(waves)
plt.show()
```

I get this output:
[image]

With the Xticks not showing.
The xaxis is a range between 0-100 and i want to be able to see these numbers (or atleast some of the).
How can i make the xticks visible?

Comment: Since the 0 is shown, you've probably just calculated `upper_x_bound` or the step size incorrectly. Using `np.linspace` would save you one of those. In the future, please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- by posting an example that we can run, you will usually get a real answer that you can  run.

Comment: The problem is the dummy call to `ax = sns.barplot()` which sets an undesired tick formatter. Use `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` instead. Optionally you can call `sns.set()` to set a Seaborn theme.